# Properties of Prime Number in Prime Ideal (Ring theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

We have the following theory:
Let $J$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $J$ is a prime ideal if and only if $J= n\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime number $n$.

**Problem**

The problem is with the proof. I understand that any ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ must be in the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ for some integers $n$. But why 
$n|xy$ if and only if $n|x$ or $n|y$ implies that $n$ is a prime number? Frankly, whenever I see the divisor sign I fret because primes feel so frightening to me, but it appears here and there in abstract algebra.

Comment: This is a little bit false since the trivial ideal is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** We have $$''n|xy \iff n|x \quad \textrm{or} \quad n|y''$$ if and only if $n$ is prime.

**Proof:**

*Only if*: We prove by contradiction. If $n$ is not prime, say $n = ab$ with neither of $a$, $b$ equal to $\pm n$, then $n|ab$ but $n \not | a$ and $n \not | b$.

*If:* If $n$ is prime, then the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (i.e., thinking about prime decompositions) tells us that the given property holds. If a prime number appears in the prime decomposition of a product of two numbers, it must appear in the prime decomposition of one of the numbers. $ \qquad\square$

Really, in ring theory, this property is the **definition** of a prime element, and it happens that the prime numbers (along with their negatives) are exactly the prime elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. The familiar definition of prime numbers actually means exactly that they (and their negatives) are the **irreducible** elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, and, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD (which is another way of stating the fundamental theorem of arithmetic), the irreducible elements are exactly the prime elements.

If you still have questions, please comment and I will try to expand my answer.

Comment: I think your explanation is already complete. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little worried that my proof may be circular in the FTA bit, as we may use this divisibility property of primes there... at any rate, if you're comfortable with FTA, then the "if" part should be okay with you, and I think you're interested in the "only if" part anyway, and the reasoning there is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In any commutative ring $R$, one defines $p\in R\setminus \{0\}$ to be a *prime element of $R$* if it is not a unit and for all $a,b\in R$, $p|ab\implies p|a\text{ or }p|b$.

With this definition you can say:

> For a nonzero $x\in R$, the principal ideal $(x)$ is a prime ideal iff $x$ is a prime element of $R$.

(This fixes the problem mentioned in the comments about the way you originally phrased it.)

This is nothing deep, it just rephrases the definition I gave above.

The case of $\mathbb Z$ is a very special one where all the ideals are principal, and the prime elements are the ones we are used to.

> Frankly, whenever I see the divisor sign I fret because primes feel so frightening to me

What? Why?  Of all abstract algebra topics, I would bet this is the most familiar and easy to grasp.

In commutative rings, divisibility is just a statement about containment between principal ideals. That is, $a|b \iff (b)\subseteq (a)$. Actually, this partial order gives the set of principal ideals of the ring the structure of a lattice order.

Rephrased with containment graphs, the definition of prime says that if:

[image]

then one of the following graphs must also hold [image]

So $p$ has a special property compared to other elements in this partial order.